# Missing return statement error with return statements for both outcomes

Tags: java

```
   public double getWeight(boolean isMetric) {
    // your code here
    if(isMetric = true) {
    return kg;
    } else if(isMetric = false) 
        return lb;      
}
```

I know that I need a return statement for every possible outcome, but because this is a boolean parameter, wouldn't that mean i only need two return statements? I tried adding a "return null" on the last line but that only leads to a "illegal start of type" error.

```
   public User(String firstName, String lastName, double weight, double height) {  
    first = firstName;
    last = lastName;
    kg = weight;
    cm = height;    
}

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, double weight, double height, boolean isMetric) {
    // your code here
    first = firstName;
    last = lastName;
    lb = weight;
    in = height;
    isMetric = false;
}
```

These are the constructors that relate to the method in question.

Comment: Remove the " if(isMetric = false) " part after the else and the syntax check will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use == and not = inside conditions:

```
if(isMetric == true) {
}
```

Now, since the if / else if conditions evaluate to boolean you can redue the code to:

```
if(isMetric) {
 ...
}
```

In addition, indeed all the method branches should return a value (and java does not have an "optimization" that checks that `else if` contains a condition on boolean expression.

Instead, you can go with the following symanically equivalent construction:

```
public double getWeight(boolean isMetric) {
   // your code here
    if(isMetric) {
      return kg;
    } else {
      return lb;  
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if(isMetric = true) {
```

that is an assignment, not a condition (= versus ==).

So, your "check" boils down to:

```
if (true) { ... return
```

and anything after the closing } is therefore dead code.

In other words: the compiler recognizes that your code will allows return kg, and therefore that else-if is never going to be executed, therefore the compiler tells you that something seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify what you had to be the following:

```
public double getWeight(boolean isMetric) {
    if (isMetric) {
        return kg;
    }
    return lb;      
}
```

There were a couple main issues with your getWeight method. `if(isMetric = true)` is assigning isMetric to true rather than comparing it to true (`=` is for assignment, `==` is for checking equality). It was complaining about missing a return because your last statement was in an unnecessary condition (`else if(isMetric = false)`) for which there is an implicit `else` without a return.